# Tuleap - Project Dashboard Missing

Tags: dashboard, tuleap

We are using Tuleap in our Organization, currently we are facing a serious issue.

We have created around 40 projects in Tuleap and all those were working fine, suddenly we find project dashboard is missing inside one of the project which was working well all these days. (i.e. the screen which appears once I click on any project from Personal Page).

The real problem is that I don't find that custom widgets option in one of the project, because of that I could not recreate card wall to the project dashboard.

The image below shows how the project dashboard appears now.  You can see the custom widget option as well the cardwall are missing.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You talk about the project dashboard yet you have attached a screenshot of the project tree. Is it that you are redirected to the project tree when you click on the link to the project dashboard? Given that this only happens on one project, I would guess that the link has been badly configured (project administration -> service conguration). The pattern should be similar to the one in a valid project.

P.S. This is more of a user question than a code question so I would guess its place would be on superuser not stackoverflow.

P.P.S Nice custom homemade theme. There is a green flaming parrot theme you might want to check-out as an alternative (> Tuleap 7.0).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i changed a ID in file then it worked, this happen when network goes down while i am configuring rest of the section or abrupt stop of service etc. Sure, I'll try green flaming parrot as well. But really thanks to you guys for your wonderful support.